# Looking up XML attributes with wildcard values, using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, wildcard

The task of my little piece of XSL is to go through all the OptionRef tags in the XML file and to print the id and the displayName attributes for the OptionRef tags. The id´s are looked-up in the Options section to find displayName.

And now, the problem: 
Some of the OptionRef id attributes use wildcards (*) as part of their values. These id´s cannot be looked-up with regards to displayName, unless they first get resolved to real id´s found in the Options section. Is there some way to extend the XSL to do this kind of "globbing"?

I would like to print the id´s and displayNames of all the id´s that are matching the wildcard.
For instance "A01*" will match both "A0101" and "A0102" in the Options section, so these id´s and their display names should be printed.

This is a sample of the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <OptionList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Group>
            <OptionRef id="A0102"/>
            <OptionRef id="A03"/>
            <OptionRef id="A04"/>
            <OptionRef id="A0101"/>
            <OptionRef id="A0102"/>
            <OptionRef id="B01"/>
        </Group>
        <Options>
            <Option displayName="Option A02" id="A02"/>
            <Option displayName="Option A03" id="A03"/>
            <Option displayName="Option A0101" id="A0101"/>
            <Option displayName="Option A0102" id="A0102"/>
            <Option displayName="Option A04" id="A04"/>
            <Option displayName="Option B01" id="B01"/>
        </Options>
        <Rules>
            <Opportunities>
                <OptionRef id="A01*">
                    <OptionRef id="A03"/>
                    <OptionRef id="A04"/>
                </OptionRef>
            </Opportunities>
            <Problems>
                <Problem>
                    <OptionRef id="A03"/>
                    <OptionRef id="A04"/>
                </Problem>
            </Problems>
        </Rules>
    </OptionList>
```

This is the XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:key name="Option_Key" match="Option" use="@id"/>

        <xsl:template match="OptionRef" >
           <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>: 
                <xsl:value-of select="key('Option_Key', @id)/@displayName"/>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you post the expected result of your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="Option_Key" match="Option" use="@id"/>
<xsl:variable name="options" select="/OptionList/Options/Option" />

<xsl:template match="OptionRef">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>: &#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@id, '*')">
            <xsl:for-each select="$options[starts-with(@id, substring-before(current()/@id, '*'))]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@displayName"/>
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('Option_Key', @id)/@displayName"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to you example input, the **result** will be:

```
A0102: 
Option A0102

A03: 
Option A03

A04: 
Option A04

A0101: 
Option A0101

A0102: 
Option A0102

B01: 
Option B01

A01*: 
Option A0101
Option A0102

A03: 
Option A03

A04: 
Option A04
```

Comment: That approach kinda defies the purpose of having a key at all. :) The whole `<xsl:choose>` could be collapsed into the first case, considerably reducing complexity.

Comment: @Tomalak I don't think so: the key is the default method to use here. Only when the id contains a wildcard, do we make an exception and resort to the less efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that...

- there only is one wildcard character (`*`)
- the wildcard can only occur at the end of the `<OptionRef>` @id
- the `<Option>` @id is 1-5 characters long

You can use:

```
<xsl:key name="Option_Key_1" match="Option" use="substring(@id, 1, 1)"/>
<xsl:key name="Option_Key_2" match="Option" use="substring(@id, 1, 2)"/>
<xsl:key name="Option_Key_3" match="Option" use="substring(@id, 1, 3)"/>
<xsl:key name="Option_Key_4" match="Option" use="substring(@id, 1, 4)"/>
<xsl:key name="Option_Key_5" match="Option" use="substring(@id, 1, 5)"/>

<xsl:template match="OptionRef">
   <xsl:variable name="id" select="substring-before(concat(@id, '*'), '*')" />
   <xsl:variable name="keyname" select="concat('Option_Key_', string-length($id))" />

   <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id, ':&#xA;')" />

   <xsl:for-each select="key($keyname, $id)">
       <xsl:value-of select="@displayName" />
       <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output with your input XML:

```
A0102:
Option A0102
A03:
Option A03
A04:
Option A04
A0101:
Option A0101
A0102:
Option A0102
B01:
Option B01
A01*:
Option A0101
Option A0102
A03:
Option A03
A04:
Option A04
A03:
Option A03
A04:
Option A04
```

---

To support @id values up to length `N`, add more keys:

```
<!-- ... -->
<xsl:key name="Option_Key_N" match="Option" use="substring(@id, 1, N)"/>
```

---

Final thoughts:

- If you can't guarantee a maximum length for @id values, the approach is not suitable.
- The creation of keys comes with a cost. Creating more keys makes the transformation start slower (but potentially run faster - it's a trade-off).
- If your input documents do not contain very many `<OptionRef>` elements, the run-time benefit you get from a key is negligible. If you care about transformation performance, measure the alternatives. If you don't, you do not need a key at all and can work with XPath directly:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="options" select="/*/Options/Option" />

  <xsl:template match="OptionRef[contains(@id, '*')]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$options[starts-with(@id, substring-before(current()/@id, '*'))]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OptionRef">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$options[@id = current()/@id]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OptionRef/@id">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ':&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Option">
    <xsl:value-of select="@displayName" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

Comment: You haven't tested this, have you?

Comment: @michael Ah, damn it. Stupid mistakes removed.

Comment: Interesting use of several keys! I do not have control over the ID lengths in the XML files, but the IDs have a certain structure where I think your solution with multiple keys could be useful.

Comment: @Gunilla If IDs and search strings have a predictable structure you could use several keys, but take care to think of all the edge cases and define behavior for them. Also explore the possibility of dropping the keys and working with pure XPath, as shown in the lower part of my answer. It's possible that the keys don't buy you enough run-time benefit to justify using them in the first place.

Comment: For the XPath solution I found out that even if there were no * at the end of the IDs, the xsl was matching more, if it could. For instance, if there were A0102, A0102.01 and A0102.02 in the Options list, the script would also match OptionRefs A0102.01 and A0102.02 when OptionRef A0102 was being looked-up. But this way I learnt some new things about the contents of the XML file.:-)

Comment: That's right, because of the `starts-with()`. I've changed my XPath-only approach.